# OrderBy Doesn't Seem To Work On Joined Tables

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

Hopefully this is just a brain fart moment for me. I have done something like this in C# in the past but it doesn't seem to sort by these properties I want in VB.

```
GetAllPhasedJobInfoesJoinedByDate_OrderedByJobNumber = DBSubs.asdbCtx.PhasedJobInfoes _
            .Include("MainJobInfo") _
            .Include("MainJobInfo.CompanyInfo") _
            .Where(Function(x) x.Delivery_Date = qryDate And Not x.IsDeleted) _
            .OrderBy(Function(x) x.MainJobInfo.Year) _
            .ThenBy(Function(x) x.MainJobInfo.Job_Number)
'The regular LINQ I tried
GetAllPhasedJobInfoesJoinedByDate_OrderedByJobNumber = From x In DBSubs.asdbCtx.PhasedJobInfoes
                                                               Join j In DBSubs.asdbCtx.MainJobInfoes
                                                                   On j Equals x.MainJobInfo
                                                               Join c In DBSubs.asdbCtx.CompanyInfoes
                                                                   On c Equals x.MainJobInfo.CompanyInfo
                                                               Where x.Delivery_Date = qryDate And Not x.IsDeleted
                                                               Order By j.Year, j.Job_Number
```

The method that calls it is this.

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    'Clear ListView Here

    Try
        phasedJobInfoes = DBSubs.GetAllPhasedJobInfoesJoinedByDate_OrderedByJobNumber(jwvDate).ToList()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error Catching Stuff Here
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Put it into a ListView Here

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

And here's a little of the Data Model.

```
[Table("PhasedJobInfo")]
public class PhasedJobInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MainJobInfo MainJobInfo { get; set; }
}

[Table("MainJobInfo")]
public class MainJobInfo
{
    public MainJobInfo()
    {
        PhasedJobInfoes = new HashSet<PhasedJobInfo>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Job_Number { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhasedJobInfo> PhasedJobInfoes { get; set; }
}

[Table("CompanyInfo")]
public partial class CompanyInfo : AllianceScheduleDBObject
{
    public CompanyInfo()
    {
        MainJobInfoes = new HashSet<MainJobInfo>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string StreetAddr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MainJobInfo> MainJobInfoes { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using a LINQ Query and I was getting a type mismatch error with something to do with the joins. So I stopped going down that route. I also tried removing the Includes and Joins all together. Order it by a NotMapped property that returns the MainJobInfo stuff I need then use that ordering to create a joined list. But, again it still didn't sort/order by. I tried sort but realized I don't think you can sort by two fields.

I'm lost for sure. If I need to add more let me know. I'm confident by using the Visual Studio that this list isn't being re-sorted elsewhere.

Comment: 1. check and posr generated SQL. 2. try regular LINQ, instead of extensions

Comment: `.Include("MainJobInfo.CompanyInfo") ` what is the `CompanyInfo`?

Comment: Oh it's another class. I'll post it. I'm just calling a string from it to put on the ListView it's used in.

Comment: @T.S. Sorry but what do you mean regular LINQ? The SQL seems fine albeit it looks a little weird but, it has the OrderBy and is referring to the right table.

Comment: Check `phasedJobInfoes` it may be that is correct and it's just the UI re-sorting it

Comment: regular LINQ is `from x in DbSet.X join....`

Comment: @Charlieface It's only taking the values in the list itself and getting a total. Then it's creating a ListViewItem and setting the ListViewItem's values to it appropriately. I can put that up if you'd like too.

Comment: @T.S. Okay I posted it but actually now I'm getting an exception. This is the error message.

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`3[AllianceScheduleDB.PhasedJobInfo,AllianceScheduleDB.MainJobInfo,AllianceScheduleDB.CompanyInfo]]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[AllianceScheduleDB.PhasedJobInfo]'.

Maybe I did my join stuff incorrectly?

Comment: you don't have `select` and assign wrong type

Comment: @T.S. Great news. The select fixed that error message and it's sorting properly now. But it's not joining. But, when I select all the tables I need I get the error message again. What type do I assign it? I'm not familiar with whatever type that DbQuery that has like three objects types in it.

Comment: ` On c Equals x.MainJobInfo.CompanyInfo` -->> aren't you supposed to have something like ` On c.SomeField Equals x.MatchingField`... where "field" is a property on your model

Comment: @T.S. I'm not sure. I think this question might be a duplicate. I spent a ton of time on this so I looked through old code and it looks like I handle all the sorting with a datagridview in the wpf app. I don't think you can use orderby when your including/joining other tables unless you create another model that would be like a view of those that you need.